# C++ array of strings destructor

Tags: c++, arrays, string, oop, destructor

i have a simple class with string pointer and size integer. Its constructor sets the size to 0 and the pointer to new string[0]; When I try to destruct the string* with delete[] the program crashes.

```
#include<string>
using std::string;
class Strarr {
private:
    string *items;
    int size;
public:
    Strarr() {
        items = new string[0];
        size = 0;
    }
    ~Strarr() {
        delete[] items;
    }
};
int main() {
    Strarr test;
    test.~Strarr();
}
```

Can someone please explain what is happening here?

Comment: Please do tell us who taught you that you should call destructors manually. Then I can call a guy who can "fix" things.

Comment: Think about that loop again, and remember that `size` is `0`. And if `size` is something else in your real code, then you have *undefined behavior* as you try to `delete` something you didn't `new`.

Comment: You know, i don't call destructors manually. I just did so to show what happens.

Comment: You *do* know that the destructor will be called anyway, when the variable `test` goes out of scope when the `main` function returns?

Comment: BTW: You don't "destruct the string* with delete[]". The pointer itself remains unchanged by the use of `delete[]`. Rather, it's the strings that it points to that are destroyed.

Comment: What happens if you don't call the destructor manually? Point is, it is **still** invoked automatically a second time after that, which is probably the point that it "crashes" (which is an interpretation, while the actual error message would be appropriate here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me show you a program I wrote :-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Some_Class
{
    public:
    Some_Class()
    {
        cout<<"constructing\n";
    }
    ~Some_Class()
    {
        cout<<"destroying\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    cout<<"executing...\n";
    Some_Class *p=new Some_Class[0];
    delete[] p;
    cout<<"executed\n";
    return 0;
}
/* OUTPUT:-
executing...
executed
*/
```

Clearly my program doesn't crash like yours. The problem probably with yours is that you are calling the `destructor` manually. In that case it will delete the `class object` twice which is an `undefined behaviour`. So never call the `destructor` manually if you haven't allocated the object `dynamically` (ie with `new` as in that case you have to call `delete`).

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. The problem isn't in deleting the array of strings, but deleting the object.

Comment: yes it is, if you find this answer satisfactory put the green tick on it